# positioning SVG element relative to sibling

Tags: javascript, svg

How can I position SVG elements relative to other siblings?  I want this to be similar to how in HTML, elements get laid out relative to each other automatically (for instance, left to right, top to bottom), except (solely) with the ability to specify an offset from the bound of the other object (since left to right AND top to bottom together don't make sense in SVG).

Currently I am trying using `getBoundingClientRect` (and then laying things out relative to the parent using `transform:translate` styling but this seems to be buggy on some platforms and difficult to deal with in certain situations.  In addition with this scheme, if any SVG element moves, the other elements don't move.  With relative positioning they would get automatically re-laid out if the SVG element they were relative to moved.

How can I do this?

Comment: SVG has no such facility to do this natively. You have to iterate over the sibilings with javascript as you are doing. If you showed your code we might be able to comment on why its buggy on some platforms.

Comment: @RobertLongson Fair enough.